# How to find the damping ratio of a 2nd order system by looking its bode diagram

Tags: control-system, transfer-function

How to find the damping ratio of a 2nd order system by looking its bode diagram ?

Suppose I have a 2nd order system which does not resonate where it is not possible to identitfy the resonant pulsation on the bode diagram. I saw that it is possible to find the natural pulsation and then if we know the damped resonant pulsation wd it is possible to find the damping ratio as follows:

[image]

Like this one :
[image]

Have a nice day :)

Comment: IIRC, There was a recently asked similar question here, and one of the suggested answer was to measure the maximum value of \$|\frac{d\Phi}{d\omega}|\$. It increases with  decrease in damping ratio. Unfortunately I can't find it by searching. I suggest that you search for the expression of the maximum derivative of the phase angle and see how it relates to the damping ratio. There may be some caveats.

Comment: Well, It will need a demonstration :) As apparently I see that the maximum value of |dΦdω| happens at the natural pulsation frequency ? Isn't it ? I do not know from my side but by visualizing the bode plot it seems to correspond.

Comment: I found the [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/565679/238590). Unfortunately it has only helpful comments; no answers. See the comments by tony and verbal. They seem promising. Slides 98 and 99 mention `Q` which is mostly the damping ratio if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you ! I will take a look on it !

Comment: I think that is the solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can estimate the damping ratio value from the Bode plot, of course. How good that estimate will be depends on the accuracy of your readings on the graph. (I redid the computation after carefully centering the reference lines and I got a slightly different result). But first and foremost you need to know what kind of transfer function you have plotted.

0. assuming this is a second order system with no zeroes (as can be inferred from the phase plot going from 0° to -180° and the 40dB/decade slope for high frequency)...

[image: more accurate pic]

1. ...since the phase resonance frequency is equal to the natural undamped frequency wn, we can find from the phase plot the value of wn = 2 pi fn
   by counting pixels and playing with scales and logarithms

[image: detail]
the pixel distance between 10k and 100k is 759
the pixel distance between 10k and f3dB is 211
the pixel distance between 10k and fn is 271

we can easily find

fn (kHz) = 10^(1+ 271/759) = 10^1.35765 = 22.75 (kHz)

so wn = 2 pi 22.75 kHz.

2. once we have traced the -3dB reference (just count the pixels in a 10 dB interval and move the horizonal reference 3/10 of that many pixel down from the low frequency plateau - or use the simulator utilities).
3. we can find the 3dB cutoff frequency. Again by counting pixels we find

f3dB (kHz) = 10^(1+ 211/759) = 10^(1.277998) = 18.967 (kHz)

we thus get w3dB = 2 pi 18.97 kHz.
the fact that w3dB < wn tells us that this is a peakless transform (might be overdamped, critically damped or underdamped)

4. we can now compute the ratio w3dB/wn that will allow us to find zeta

w3dB/wn = 18.967/22.75 = 0.8337...

(my previous lazy eyeball estimate was 20/22.53 = 0.8876. Kinda prove my point that the accuracy of the results relies on how carefully you get the values)

Note that the fact that w3dB > 0.644 wn tells us that we are in the underdamped case where, since w3dB < wn, there is no peak in the transfer function.

[image: blblblb]
<sub>Relative position of 3dB cutoff frequency with respect to natural undamped frequency wn allows us to tell whether the second order transfer function without zeroes belongs to a: overdamped (w3dB < 0.644 wn), critically damped (w3dB = 0.644 wn) or underdamped (w3dB > 0.644 wn) system and even if the magnitude of the transfer function has a peak (w3dB > wn) or not ( 0.644 wn < w3dB < wn). The above graph shows the TF for two distinct real poles (whose partial contributes are shown) for zeta = 1.75, that is for an overdamped system, and dashed, the curve for a critically damped system with two identical real poles)</sub>

We have to expect a value of zeta greater than 1/sqrt(2) =  0.707...

4. By equating the magnitude of the transfer function to the -3dB level, that is to 1/sqrt(2), or better yet, the square of the magnitude to 1/2, we can find after a bit of boring, elementary algebra:

[image: dfffd]

Solving for w3dB/wn = 0.8337 we find

zeta = 0.828
(and wd = 0.56 wn)

This new, hopefully more accurate estimate for zeta is even farther away from the frontier between the no-peak vs peak regions of the underdamped zone.
If the assumption we made about the transfer function is correct, then we are in the underdamped region (zeta < 1) where there is no peak (zeta > 0.707).

[image: kjkjk]
 The boundary bewteen the "No peak" and "Resonance peak" regions in the underdamped zone is at zeta = 1/sqrt(2) = 0.707...

If we round the 3dB frequency at 19 kHz, with w3dB/wn = 10/22.75 =  we get zeta = 0.827. In any case, that's a far cry from the critically damped case of zeta=1 and not even particularly close to the border between the "there is a peak" and "there is not a peak" set by zeta = 1/sqrt[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0J1b.png) = 0.707... (corresponding to w3dB=0.644 wn). The poles are complex conjugates with an angle of 56° wrt to the imaginary axis and 34° with respect to the negative real axis (the peak no-peak border requires an angle of 45°)

I suggest you redo the computation after having extracted your values from the graph. Better yet, do it on a known function to assess the accuracy of the method.
See also my last answer to the question [Finding resonant frequency or damping ratio from Bode Plot](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565679/finding-resonant-frequency-or-damping-ratio-from-bode-plot?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Really nice explanation !

Comment: Could you explain how you find the relation betwenn the natural pulsation wn and the 3db pulsation w3dB and the damping ratio just above the point "4. Solving" ?

Comment: @Jess  edited in. You can find that on most control and electronics books. It's just calculus (quite boring if done by hand, a clilk or two with a CAS). See for example "Transistor Amplifiers" by Feucht. Bye.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it looks close to having a damping ratio of the reciprocal of \$\sqrt2\$ but, if you need 1 or 2 decimal places then I'd simulate a 2nd order filter made from an inductor, capacitor and resistor and play around with the values until it perfectly matched what you have in your diagram.

A simple low-pass 2nd order filter has its natural resonant frequency when the phase plot has a 90° lag so, this is fairly easy enough to locate on your picture: -

[image]

Knowing the natural resonant frequency does not however indicate what the damping ratio is. Damping is uncovered by the shape of the amplitude plot.

Another clue to the damping ratio is when projecting the 45° point (natural resonant frequency) up to the amplitude plot and looking at the dB loss relative to much lower frequencies: -

[image]

I estimate that there is about a 5 dB droop at 22 kHz and if zeta were exactly 0.7071 the droop would be 3.01 dB. This tells us that damping is a little greater than 0.7071. And, we can graphically find zeta by using an [on-line tool](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html) and messing with the values of a typical 2nd order low pass filter: -

[image]

I have set R = 128.5 Ω, L = 523 μH and C = 100 nF. This results in a natural damped frequency of 22.007 kHz and an attenuation at this frequency of 4.993 dB. The damping ratio shown in the picture above is 0.8884.

Now, if you applied a step change to the input and looked at the output overshoot you will see around a 0.2% overshoot: -

[image]

The 1 volt step change results in a peak of 1.00228 volts on the output after around 48.8 μs i.e. it is very small.

Comment: Hello Andy! A pleasure to see you again . I edited the post with a formula. Is it possible to find the damped natural frequency wd ? Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: @Jess well, if you assume the damping ratio is about 0.7071, then \$\sqrt{1-0.7071^2} \$ equals, believe it or not 0.7071. Hence fd (Hz) is about 156 kHz.

Comment: That was not what I wanted to say. Suppose it is possible to find the damped natural frequency wd by looking the bode plot, as you know the natural frequency wn by looking the bode plot, thank to the formula you will be able to find the damping ratio.

Comment: I have amended my picture because I misread the frequency as being ten times too high. Note also that in the comment above I should have said 15.6 kHz. For your particular graph @Jess there is nothing to identify in the picture for wd because the response is near enough flat. When it is this flat you can only really say that zeta = 0.7071 approximately.

Comment: Thank you ! I will try to see it :)

Comment: @Jess no point in looking because there is no peak to be seen in the frequency response. If you applied a signal to the input and looked at the step response output you would see some perturbation. - I'm adding that extra picture to help you see this but, bear in mind that the overshoot will be around 0.2% for a step change.

Comment: If I calcul the gain at the natural frequency, as w=wn, it simplifies the gain of the transfer function and I can find the damping ratio if I have the DC  gain. I obtain ksi = DC_gain/[2*Gain(Wn)]. It seems to fit your result ! I will just verify it with matlab. But I have some troubles to get a PC ...